# ¿Cómo hago para llenar una matriz de 4x5 de la forma en que esta la foto?

Tags: java, array

Se supone que el programa cuente de 0 a 19 y vaya asignando números consecutivos, recorriendo la matriz en forma diagonal, así como se ve en la imagen:

[image: Así debo ordenar la matriz: 0 2 5 9 13 | 1 4 8 12 16 | 3 7 11 15 18 | 6 10 14 17 19]

Lo hice así y me da el resultado igual que en la imagen, pero no me parece que este bien el metodo usado.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[][]=new int [4][5];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a.length+1;j++){
            a[1][0]=a[0][0]+1;
            a[0][1]=a[1][0]+1;
            a[2][0]=a[0][1]+1;
            a[1][1]=a[2][0]+1;
            a[0][2]=a[1][1]+1;
            a[3][0]=a[0][2]+1;
            a[2][1]=a[3][0]+1;
            a[1][2]=a[2][1]+1;
            a[0][3]=a[1][2]+1;
            a[3][1]=a[0][3]+1;
            a[2][2]=a[3][1]+1;
            a[1][3]=a[2][2]+1;
            a[0][4]=a[1][3]+1;
            a[3][2]=a[0][4]+1;
            a[2][3]=a[3][2]+1;
            a[1][4]=a[2][3]+1;
            a[3][3]=a[1][4]+1;
            a[2][4]=a[3][3]+1;
            a[3][4]=a[2][4]+1;

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0;j<a.length+1;j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+"\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Hay alguna lógica que se deba seguir? ¿Puedes explicarla?

Comment: Como ves en la imagen, es como si contaras de 0 a 19, pero vas contando en diagonal, así como la dirección en la que van las flechas.

Comment: *Lo hice así y me da el resultado igual que en la imagen, pero no me parece que este bien el metodo usado.* Si tienes una forma de lograr lo que buscas, entonces ¿cual es el propósito de la pregunta? ¿Cual es realmente el objetivo de la pregunta? ¿Es una tarea escolar? ¿Hay ciertos criterios que se tengan que respetar para que se considere una buena solución?

Comment: Es una tarea escolar, y el propósito de mi pregunta es saber si existe un mejor método que el que muestro para lograr lo que esta en la imagen. @sstan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Recorrer una matriz `M x N` por las diagonales**

En una matriz `M x N`, consideremos los índices de cada posición de la matriz.

```
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1)
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2) (4,2)
(0,3) (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) (4,3)
```

Hay una propiedad muy interesante: si sumamos los índices x + y, obtenemos ***el número de cada diagonal***.

```
(0)   (1)   (2)   (3)   (4)
(1)   (2)   (3)   (4)   (5)
(2)   (3)   (4)   (5)   (6)
(3)   (4)   (5)   (6)   (7)
```

De esta forma, para cada diagonal se tiene que llenar.

```
Diagonal 0: (0,0)
Diagonal 1: (0,1) (1,0)
Diagonal 2: (0,2) (1,1) (2,0)
Diagonal 3: (0,3) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0)
Diagonal 4: (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,0)
Diagonal 5: (2,3) (3,2) (4,1)
Diagonal 6: (3,3) (4,2)
Diagonal 7: (4,3)
```

Y la cantidad de diagonales será siempre `M + N - 1`.

Por ejemplo, para `4 x 5`, `4 + 5 - 1 = 8`, son 8 diagonales (de 0 a 7).

Entonces, podemos recorrer:

- Las diagonales desde `0`, mientras sea menor a `n + m - 1`.
- En cada diagonal, completando las filas desde `y = diagonal` hasta `0`, con `x = diagonal - y`.

  - siempre que `y` no exceda su dimensión `m`
    **⇒** `y` va desde `Math.min(diagonal,m - 1)` hasta `0`
  - siempre que `x` no exceda su dimensión `n`
    **⇒** `x < n`
  - incrementando `num` luego de cada asignación
    **⇒** `a[y][x] = num++;`.

**Código:**

```java
final int n = 5;
final int m = 4; //funciona para cualquier (n,m)
final int cantDiagonales = n + m - 1;

int a[][] = new int[m][n];

for (int diagonal = 0, num = 0; diagonal < cantDiagonales; diagonal++) {

    for (int x, y = Math.min(diagonal,m - 1); y >= 0 && (x = diagonal - y) < n; y--) {
        a[y][x] = num++;
    }

}
```

**Resultado:**

```
0   2   5   9   13  
1   4   8   12  16  
3   7   11  15  18  
6   10  14  17  19
```

**Demo:**

<kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y7iUvH)</kbd>

Comment: Un excelente análisis sobre la situación.

Answer (score 2):

> el propósito de mi pregunta es saber si existe un *mejor* método que el que muestro para lograr lo que esta en la imagen

La dificultad es que la expresión *mejor método* es muy subjetiva.

Ahora bien, si el criterio fuera que el algoritmo que llena la matriz en secuencias diagonales deba funcionar con matrices de *cualquier dimensión*, ahora sí, puedo entender la necesidad de un *mejor método*.

Si fuera ese el caso, yo implementaría el algoritmo de esta manera (nota que `dimX` y `dimY` pueden ser ajustados para cambiar la dimensión de la matriz):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int dimX = 4;
    final int dimY = 5;

    int a[][] = new int[dimX][dimY];

    for (int cnt = 0, 
             total = dimX * dimY,
             x = 0,
             y = 0;
         cnt < total; 
         cnt++) {

        a[x][y] = cnt;

        // mover en diagonal dirección noreste.
        x--;
        y++;

        // si quedó fuera de los límites del rectángulo,
        // mover al comienzo de la próxima fila en diagonal.
        if (x < 0 || x >= dimX || y < 0 || y >= dimY) {
            y++;
            int delta = Math.min(y, dimX - x - 1);
            x += delta;
            y -= delta;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < dimX; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < dimY; y++) {
            if (y != 0) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.print(a[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
0   2   5   9   13  
1   4   8   12  16  
3   7   11  15  18  
6   10  14  17  19
```

Aun así, estoy seguro que existen *mejores métodos*.