# Imprimir una matriz java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de imprimir una matriz en diagonal, es decir, en la de

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

imprima 1 2 4 3 5 7 6 8 9

Tengo esto, en la que solo me imprime hasta el 7 por que si no se sale de la matriz:

```
public class matriz {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lado; i++) {
        x = i;
        y = 0;
        while (x >= 0) {

            System.out.print(matriz[y][x] + " ");
            x--;
            y++;

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Otro problema que tengo es el imprimir una parte de la matriz, imprimir la triangular inferior de la misma de manera inversa, donde tiene que imprimir 9 8 7 5 4 1, me imprime 9 8 5 7 4 1, intercalando dos números de posición. El código:

```
public class matrizmas {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    for (int i = lado - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = lado - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            System.out.print(matriz[j][i]);

        }

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

  }
}
```

Comment: "intercalando dos números" o cambiando de posicion?  ademas, no tenias ya una pregunta de matrizes triangulares con fallos de impresion??

Comment: @lois6b Están cambiados de posición. Esa duda ya la tenia resuelta, esta es otra. Me cuesta ver las diferentes formas de imprimir las matrices, solo consigo el que me imprima una parte o lo haga mal.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo así

```
public class Matriz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        imprimirMatriz(matriz);
    }

    public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
        // limite es el indice maximo de un lado
        int limite = matriz.length;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*limite-1 ; i++) {
            // aquí discriminas si y cuanto i sobresale la dimensión de
            // la matriz. en vez de aumentar x, la diferencia se agrega a y 
            x = (i<limite) ? i : limite-1;
            y = (i<limite) ? 0 : i-limite+1;
            // también tenemos que asegurarnos que el puntador
            // no sobresale y
            while (x >= 0 && y < limite) {

                System.out.print(matriz[y][x] + " ");
                x--;
                y++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consola:

```
1 2 4 3 5 7 6 8 9
```

el siguiente código

```
x = (condicion) ? valor : otroValor;
```

es una forma mas corta de escribir

```
if ( condicion ) {
    x = valor;
} else {
    x = otroValor;
}
```

Alternativamente puedes hacerlo como en el siguiente ejemplo para matrices de otras dimensiones:

```
public class Matriz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Matriz matriz=new Matriz(5); 
        matriz.imprimirMatriz();
    }

    private int [][] matriz;
    private int dimension;

    public Matriz(int dimension){
        this.dimension = dimension;
        matriz = new int[dimension][dimension];
        generarMatriz();
    }

    private final void generarMatriz(){
        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x++){
                matriz[x][y]=1+x+y*dimension;
                System.out.print(String.format("%02d ",matriz[x][y]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private boolean outBounds(int x, int y){
        return ( x<0 || x>=dimension || y<0 || y>=dimension );
    }

    private void imprimirDiagonal(int a, int b){
        int x = a;
        int y = b;
        do{
            System.out.print(String.format("%d ", matriz[x--][y++]));
        }while(!outBounds( x, y ));
    }

    public void imprimirMatriz(){
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x++ ) imprimirDiagonal( x, 0 );
        for (int y = 1; y < dimension; y++ ) imprimirDiagonal( dimension-1, y );
    }

}
```

Comment: No entiendo cuando pones lo de la x e y lo de la ? y : a que te refieres con ello.

Comment: te lo explico en la respuesta.

Comment: Ya se que lo explicas en la respuesta con comentarios, pero es la primera vez que veo eso de la ? y los :, por eso que no entiendo esa parte.

Comment: @Fernando busca operador condicional u operador ternario ? en Google y te lo explican.

Comment: @Fernando te dije "te lo explico", no "te lo expliqué". Había añadido una explicación en la respuesta después que preguntaste.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo también de esta forma

```
public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
  int lado = matriz[0].length;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int yAux = 0;
  int yAnt = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int xAnt = -1;
  boolean terminado = false;
  while (!terminado) {
    x = (i < lado ? i : lado -1);
    yAux = (x != xAnt ? yAux : yAux + 1);
    y = (yAux < lado ? yAux : lado -1);
    xAnt = x;
    yAnt = (y == lado -1 ? yAnt + 1 : yAnt);
    terminado = (yAnt > 0 ? true : false);
    while (x >= 0 && y < lado) {
        System.out.print(matriz[y][x] + " ");
        x--;
        y++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

En cuanto a tu segundo problema así se soluciona

```
 public static void imprimirMatriz2(int[][] matriz) {
  int lado = matriz.length;
  for (int i = lado - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Y en el primer código, cuando pones lo de = y : a que te refieres con ello? Es la primera vez que lo veo... estoy empezando poco a poco.  En la segunda parte me confundí al ponerlo, quise poner 9 8 7 4 5 1: Voy a ver si me sale modificarlo

Comment: Se conoce como if ternario, solo puede tomar dos valores
Variable = (condicion ? valor a imprimir si se cumple la condicion : valor si no)
x = 1;
int z = (y == 3 ? x : 0);

en el ejemplo de arriba z va a valer 3 el valor de la x que es 1 si y es igual a 3, y 0 si no lo es.

Si aun te quedo duda con el nombre puedes buscar mas información *if ternario*

Answer (score 1):

Bueno todas las respuestas son buenas, yo te traigo una versión que hace lo mismo que tu quieres llegar, usando ciclos de control for, que a mi parecer se usan mas para recorrer matrize.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    //imprimimos la primer matriz
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
    System.out.println();
    //imprimimos la segunda
    imprimirMatrizInversa(matriz);
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    int fila = lado;
    int columna = lado;
    //Para este ciclo aremos que recorra una  fila de mas para poder recorrer todas
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * (fila - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++) {
            //restamos la fila menos la columna
            int x = i - j;
            //aqui validamos si x es mayo o igual a cero y que x sea menor a la longitud de la matriz
            //entonces imprimimos
            if (x >= 0 && x < matriz.length) {
                System.out.print(matriz[j][x]+" ");
            }
        }

    }
}

public static void imprimirMatrizInversa(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    int fila = lado;
    int columna = lado;
    /**
     * Para la matriz inversa o como gustes llamarle se empieza desde la ultima posicion menos 1
     */
    for (int i = fila-1; i >=0; i--) {
        /**
         * Lo mismo aplica para recorrer las columnas empezamos de la ultima posicion menos 1
         */
        for (int j = columna-1 ; j>=0 ;j--)
            //imprimimos el resultado
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");

        //AHora bien para hacer el resultado que quieres despues de imprimir vamos restando una columna
        //por fila recorrida
        columna--;
    }
}
}
```

**Tu resultado**

```
1 2 4 3 5 7 6 8 9  
9 8 7 5 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el [ejemplo que ponía @Mariano en esta otra pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32069/c%c3%b3mo-hago-para-llenar-una-matriz-de-4x5-de-la-forma-en-que-esta-la-foto) y que te recomiendo que leas, te propongo esta otra solución más compacta que aprovecha una propiedad que tiene la matriz en la que la suma de los índices de una diagonal dan el mismo resultado.

El código para una matriz(n,m) para tu método `imprimirMatriz` quedaría:

```
public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int m = matriz[0].length;
    int n = matriz.length;
    String salida = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < n + m - 1; i++){
        for (int x, y = Math.min(i,m - 1); y >= 0 && (x = i - y) < n; y--) {
            salida += matriz[x][y] + " ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(salida.trim());
}
```

Que da la siguiente salida en tu caso:

> 1 2 4 3 5 7 6 8 9

Si añadieras una columna de ceros al final y dejase de ser cuadrada también funciona y da este resultado:

> 1 2 4 3 5 7 0 6 8 0 9 0

De esta forma si quieres imprimir sólo una parte de la matriz puedes jugar con los valores que puede tomar `i` (en vez de empezar por 0 y terminar en n+m-1 puedes pasarlo sólo por n-1 para imprimir una diagonal, etc...)